# PowerBI Hide 0 Values in the Page | PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Could someone advice how could be hide 0 values from all chars on the PowerBI page? 
For example when I clicking on chart A and want to filter just specific Axis, report filtering data on chart B, but also shows me lines with 0 values. 
How could be these lines deleted?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make bar chart order values in DESC order after you choose value on another chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561233/how-to-make-bar-chart-order-values-in-desc-order-after-you-choose-value-on-anoth)

Comment: @key Does the above link help?

Comment: @Joe, thanks. Exactly what I looked.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a dax measure? then you can add the below to measure to display blank instead of zero.

```
MeasureName:= If([measure]=0,blank(),[measure])
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide 0 values for a particular chart, you can just select the chart and set up a visual level filter:

[image: filter]

Comment: I tried to add it, but does not work for me. I have two charts. Chart A on which I clicked one row and want to see only values what is > 0 on the Chart B

Comment: You have to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can understand and pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Hello added print screen with example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You could use Edit Interactions and change from highlight to filter on the 2nd visual