# How to make bar chart order values in DESC order after you choose value on another chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a Treemap chart that represents locations and bar charts that represents agents.

When I click on one of the location I want agents be filtered in DESC order by money value.

For example, I clicked on Modesto location and bar chart highlights particular people that are not in order. Any way not to display NOT highlighted values at all or bring them all the way on a bottom?

I know that I can use the slicer with locations for that, but I want Treemap act as a filter in this situation. 
Is it possible?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select treemap to make it active.
Turn on Visual Interactions by selecting it from the top menu bar. Notice the filter and highlight icons that appear when you hover over the other visualizations on the report page.

Select the filter symbol on the bar chart.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are cross-highlighting. I believe you want to cross-filter instead.

Click on Format > Edit Interactions, select the treemap visual and on the bar chart choose the funnel icon to filter instead of the pie icon to highlight. See image below for reference:

[image: Reference image]